# Flask app throwing not found error on heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask app that is a login system. I have created a heroku app, linked it to `postgresql` correctly, and the app successfully deploys to heroku. However, when I visit the address, I am shown by this error: `Not Found. The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again`.

I am not sure why this error is coming up. I tried doing `heroku logs --tail`. To which it shows:

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myapptestlogin-portal.herokuapp.com request_id=42f306fd-32a2-4a84-8b02-a139f8ec46dd fwd="" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=547 protocol=https
```

When I run this in local, it works. Can someone please explain why `login.html` is not loading on heroku?

```
# app.py

from flask import Flask, Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, flash, session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin, login_user, logout_user, login_required, current_user, LoginManager

from flask_user import UserManager, roles_required


auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)
db = SQLAlchemy()
app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://myaddress'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

from app import auth as auth_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)


app.config['USER_ENABLE_EMAIL'] = False




class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) # primary keys are required by SQLAlchemy
    username = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='user_roles',
            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

    def has_roles(self, *args):
        return set(args).issubset({role.name for role in self.roles})

# Define the Role data model
class Role(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)

# Define the UserRoles data model
class UserRoles(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))


user_manager = UserManager(app, db, User)
user_manager.login_manager = LoginManager()
user_manager.login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
user_manager.login_manager.init_app(app)

db.init_app(app)

@user_manager.login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


@auth.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect('/login')

@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")


        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Procfile:
`web: gunicorn app:app --bind 0.0.0.0:${PORT}`

requirements.txt:

```
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.18.35
botocore==1.21.35
click==8.0.1
Flask==2.0.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
greenlet==1.1.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
jmespath==0.10.0
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
psycopg2==2.9.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
s3transfer==0.5.0
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.23
urllib3==1.26.6
Werkzeug==2.0.1
```

Comment: Shouldn't you pass address as 0.0.0.0 to make it visible? I believe that by default (for security) it's only localhost. Also, you have broken decorators - there are no @s in auth.route, so if it's the real code, the paths are not linked at all

Comment: The broken decorators was simply a typo. I have fixed that @h4z3

Comment: I tried replacing `app.run()` with `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`. But this did not change anything. @h4z3

Comment: What's in your Procfile?

Comment: I have updated the question to include my Procfile @h4z3

Comment: Any idea what the issue could be? @h4z3

Comment: Did you specify a port when trying to connect? By default, flask uses port 5000. And if you don't specify what port you use during connecting in your browser, port is assumed based on protocol (80 for http).

Comment: You also don't have any binding in your gunicorn command - you might need to specify the 0.0.0.0 (and port) there as well

Comment: I just tried with `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)`. It still shows the same error... is there anything else I can try to solve this issue? @h4z3

Comment: As I said, you don't have any bindings in your gunicorn command in Procfile. Try adding `--bind 0.0.0.0:5000` in there as well

Comment: And you haven't replied as to whether you add port when connecting. Do you connect to it as `http://heroku_hostname_here:5000/` or just with the heroku hostname?

Comment: Okay. I have added the changes I made to the code in the question. Refer to app.run() to see what I added as well as the Procfile. I have also binded the port to heroku using `heroku config:add PORT=5000`. Still, I get that same error @h4z3

Comment: I just noticed... your log shows `protocol=https` at the end. Try specifically http, not https.

Comment: What if I want it to strictly be https for security? Is that not possible? @h4z3

Comment: So it seems all I had to do to fix the issue was remove `from app import auth as auth_blueprint` and `app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)` and replace `@auth.route` with `@app.route`. Not sure why, but this works

Comment: Oh... I didn't think about it. But it makes sense: you first should add routes by doing .route and after that register the blueprint. You did it the other way around here.